# How to correctly format and utilise where within an oledb select count statement

Tags: c#, excel, count, oledb, oledbcommand

For the past two days I have been hunting the internet and attempting to find a method that will connect to an excel spreadsheet and essentially perform the countif function on excel, I have tried so many variations! 
I have a function that looks like the following;

```
public double GetInProgressOledb(string type, OleDbConnection FTPYBuildOleDbConnection, string AssyColumn, DateTime Selection)
{
    const string prodParamName = "@prod";
    double lastDayOfMonth = (new DateTime(Selection.Year, Selection.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)).ToOADate();
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = FTPYBuildOleDbConnection;
        comm.CommandText = string.Format(ci, "SELECT Count(*) FROM [" + type + "$" + AssyColumn + ":" + AssyColumn + "] WHERE [" + AssyColumn + "$] = #" + lastDayOfMonth + "#");
        //comm.Parameters.Add(prodParamName, OleDbType.VarChar);
        //comm.Parameters[prodParamName].Value = lastDayOfMonth;
        double rowCount = Convert.ToDouble((int)comm.ExecuteScalar());
        return rowCount;
    }
}
```

1. string type = "Beacon Comm" this is the sheet name.
2. TargetBuildOledbConnection =
   @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + FTPYTracker +
   "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';"
3. string AssyColumn = "F" or whichever colum to search string InspColumn is the same
4. DateTimeSelection = "03/01/2020 00:00:00" or data from a date picker
   in the same format.
5. ci = new CultureInfo("en-Gb")

Currently the following select statement returns the count of all possible cells in the searched sheet and column, however I cannot filter it at all! I want to be able to count where cells in F are less than the last day of a selected month and cells in G are null / empty.

```
comm.CommandText = string.Format(ci, "SELECT Count(*) FROM [" + type + "$" + AssyColumn + ":" + AssyColumn +"]");
```

I have asked a similar question before to no avail, two days working around  the same wall has broken me!